# How to use system theme Icon for QPushButton -- Qt Designer on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, qt-designer

How can I use default Qt icons for newly created QtPushButton's in Qt Designer?

Answer (score 2):

Add \src\gui\styles\qstyle_wince.qrc to your resources and set the icon property of the PushButton in Designer (assuming you want Windows Style).

Comment: I believe this answer is correct for Windows users, I am using Gentoo Linux.

Comment: Hmm, SO won't let you post comments beginning with `-1`... Anyway, *this comment could be improved* by addressing Linux.